# Github Page - Sitio reportado como inseguro

Tags: github, github-pages

Cree una página con Github Page y todo está bien excepto que cuando accedo me dice que insegura

[image: Esto es lo que me muestra]

No tengo el Enforce HTTPS porque no tengo un dominio personalizado existe forma de resolver o de plano no se puede?

Mi sitio: https://christiand0r.github.io/portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede ocurrir porque tu servidor/hosting/sitio web, pudo haber sido infectado con algun tipo de Malware.

Sin embargo, aunque no existe una solución inmediata que lo arregle todo, debes tener en cuenta que los navegadores, siempre revisan la lista de Google Safe Brawsing, para poder determinar si un sitio es malicioso

Revisa tu sitio con la herramienta de chequeo de Google Safe Browsing

Tambien, puedes guiarte con el siguiente articulo de Google acerca de la pirateria de Sitios WEB [aquí](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/security/what-is-hacked?hl=es)